# Scrolling div's content with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Can you guys tell me what is wrong with this script.
It suppose to scroll parent element's content to child element after 20 seconds delay.
Parent is overflow hidden scrolling stuff without scrollbar but I think that is irrelevant.

Edit: Typo and changed #childelement to href. It is still not working. I have href element in child element where it suppose to scroll.

```
<script>
setTimeout(
function(){

var target = $( $(this).attr('href'));

if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#parentelement').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
},
20000
);
</script>
```

Comment: `$( $(this).attr('#childelement')` – I seriously doubt that you have an HTML _attribute_ with the attribute _name_ `#childelement` …

Comment: I tried to modify this http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Syntax Error in this line :

```
var target = $( $(this).attr('#childelement');
```

you forget to close the parentheses !!

```
var target = $( $(this).attr('#childelement'));
```

another syntax error , there is no html attribute can be called `#childelement`

some legal html attributes `class`  `id` `href` ect ..

Example :

```
var className = $('.ClassName').attr('class');
```

And for your task this is what you need :

```
  setTimeout(function() {

    var target = $( $('a[href^="#"]').attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

    }, 2000);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf02nxk4/)**

This is will fires the scroll animation after 2 seconds like you expect it to do .

Comment: Thank you. This is just like it should be. Only changed 'html, body' to parent div :)